# Angularjs ngResource '@id'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, angularjs

I have a quick question.  In angular js where (like which object) does the '@id' come from in the following piece of code from a rails app?

```
var User = $resource("/users/:id", {id: '@id'});
```

I know it sets the default id.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the AngularJs [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource):

> "If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value of that
>   parameter is extracted from the data object (useful for non-GET
>   operations)."

This means that when calling a non-GET operation, like POST, you can pass the id as one of the fields of the data object you include in the call.

Comment: So what is the data object in the case of a rails app?

Comment: var User = $resource("/users/:userId", {userId: '@id'}); if you have a user with an id ( var user = new User({id : 1}) ) then if you call user.$save() it will send a post request with this url /users/1 (userId take the value of the id property)